# Lisp: Squaring all values in a list

Tags: list, lisp, element

Please bear with me as I am still fairly new to lisp. The goal of my function (in this case called test) is to square all the values in a list and return a new list.

For example, original list `(1 2 3)`.
The new list should be `(1 4 9)`

This is currently what I have so far,

```
(defun test (n)
  (cond ((null n) nil)
        (t (cons * (car n) (car n))
           (test (cdr n)))))
```

However i keep getting an error and am quite unsure as to how to proceed. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is done with `(mapcar (lambda (x) (* x x)) yourlist)`, or `(mapcar #'* yourlist yourlist)`. The most important thing in Lisp programming is to leverage the existing language and its library, and idioms like using higher order functions with applicators such as `mapcar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code there are two problems: syntax of `cond` (the equivalent of `else` of other languages is `T`), and the fact that the multiplication operator is missing.

This is a working version:

```
(defun test (n)
  (cond ((null n) nil)
        (t (cons (* (car n) (car n))
                 (test (cdr n))))))
```

Moreover, note that `cond` is most commonly used when there are multiple conditions, while `if` is used for a single condition:

```
(defun test (n)
  (if (null n)
      nil
      (cons (* (car n) (car n))
            (test (cdr n)))))
```

Comment: ahhh i forgot about t! And thanks so much i forgot to include the multiplication operator as well, I shall modify that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but im having trouble calling a separate function from within this one called test. I keep getting a function undefined error when I call it

Comment: I think you should post a new question showing your code and the exact error that you are getting.